# Django CMS using nginx and gunicorn in virtualenv renders html from version 3.4.4 after upgrade to 3.4.5 - where is the caching?

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn, virtualenv

I set up a django-cms installation version 3.4.4 with nginx and gunicorn. Then I removed the installation and installed the new 3.4.5 version.

Pip confirms this worked:

`(myenv) user@s23:~/myenv$ pip3 list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
cmsplugin-filer (1.1.3)
dj-database-url (0.4.2)
Django (1.8.18)
django-appconf (1.0.2)
django-classy-tags (0.8.0)
django-cms (3.4.5)
(...)`

When I run the server via `manage.py`, things work:

`python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:62034.1:62034
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 23, 2018 - 14:28:33
Django version 1.8.18, using settings 'proj.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:62034/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[23/Jan/2018 14:28:41] "GET /de/ HTTP/1.0" 200 13110
[23/Jan/2018 14:28:41] "GET /static/cms/css/3.4.5/cms.base.css HTTP/1.0" 304 0
[23/Jan/2018 14:28:41] "GET /static/cms/css/3.4.5/cms.welcome.css HTTP/1.0" 304 0
[23/Jan/2018 14:28:41] "GET /static/cms/js/dist/3.4.5/bundle.toolbar.min.js HTTP/1.0" 304 0`

Starting the server with nginx works fine:

`(myenv) user@s23:~/proj$ ~/init/proj start
Starting svp .....................OK
(myenv) user@s23:~/proj$ ~/init/nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx.
(myenv) user@s23:~/proj$ ps aux hf | grep user | grep gunicorn
user    22837  0.0  0.0  34560   976 pts/1    S+   14:55   0:00  |           \_ grep gunicorn
user    22410  0.0  0.0  89752 21572 ?        S    14:54   0:00 /home/user/v/bin/python3 /home/user/v/bin/gunicorn -D -b unix:////home/user/proj/proj.sock --worker-class gevent --workers 1 --pid /home/user/proj/proj.pid proj.wsgi
user    22415  1.4  0.0 174392 55916 ?        S    14:54   0:00  \_ /home/user/v/bin/python3 /home/user/v/bin/gunicorn -D -b unix:////home/user/proj/proj.sock --worker-class gevent --workers 1 --pid /home/user/proj/proj.pid proj.wsgi`

BUT, when I browse to the admin page or frontend, I'm informed that I'm still using version 3.4.4 and static files from this version are queried. This happens with other browsers as well, so it is not a client-side caching issue. So where are these html files be cached?

Answer (score 0):

I executed `runserver` on the `myenv` environment, but had the variable `DAEMON` in `~/init/proj` set to `$HOME/v/bin/gunicorn` which is a different virtualenv. On this virtualenv I still had the old django-cms version installed, thus the problem. Installing the new django version in the other virtualenv solves the problem.